# Saving user input as a variable in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game in which the user inputs an amount of money they want to bet and then if they win/lose, the purse is updated. After they input the amount they want to take, Pygame is not recognizing it as a variable and will not continue. Message I get is

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "
```

How do I get Pygame to store the amount entered as a variable?

```
money =  50

amount = ""

stake = int(amount)

new_balance = money + stake
```

Comment: `amount = ""` makes amount an empty string and you cant convert that to int. If it's a numeric string, then it will work.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the input it the sample code?

Comment: We don't have enough information to work with here. Please see: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
amount = raw_input('Please enter a number: ')
```

if you want to get user input.

Also, you can use error handling:

```py
amount = raw_input('...')
stake = 0
try:
  stake = int(amount)
except Exception:  # this is raised if the input is invalid i.e. not numeric
  pass  # does nothing
```